# C# binary strings respecting endianess

Tags: c#, binary, endianness

Up and on I meet the need to see the binary/hex representation of some data (tcp packets, files, binary serialization of some data structures,...) and it seems I always stumble accross the same issues with endianess and byte order every time I write the string conversion.

There are already other questions about this topic but I somehow seem to have some problem with my specific implementation.

I try to write myself a few functions to convert any byte/byte array into a binary string (in blocks of 8 since the included functions give only the "bits used") but the problem is I get different results. And I don't know where I have to take care about the endianess of the underlaying system.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            //ushort x = 13;
            ushort x = 3328;
            string res = ToBinaryString(x);
            string res2 = ToBinaryString(BitConverter.GetBytes(x));
            Console.WriteLine("res:  " + res + "\r\n" + "res2: " + res2);
        }

        public static string ToBinaryString(byte v)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(v, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
        }

        public static string ToBinaryString(byte[] v)
        {
            string[] strArr = new string[v.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            {
                strArr[i] = ToBinaryString(v[i]);
            }
            return string.Join("", strArr);
        }

        public static string ToBinaryString(ushort v)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(v, 2).PadLeft(16, '0');
        }
    }
}
```

The unexpected different output is:

```
res:  0000110100000000
res2: 0000000000001101
```

So I am a bit confused because so far I thought those two approaches would return the same (correct) result and not a different one.

Noteworthy: I am on a windows dev machine.

Comment: Are you looking for [`IsLittleEndian`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian?view=net-5.0)? But rather than checking the endianness explicitly, just use something like [`NetworkToHostOrder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder?view=net-5.0).

Comment: No. Currently I am not already checking for IsLittleEndian but I am already thinking about it where to use it (in the ToBinaryString(ushort) or toBinaryString(byte[]) method.

Since the methods are independend of networks I am not sure if NetworkToHostOrder is usable for me right now. But definitly if come to the part when I use the functions for debugging TCP packets.

Comment: @monty One has to note that the order of bytes in the array returned by the BitConverter.GetBytes method depends on whether the machine is little-endian or big-endian. I.e. byteArray[0] contatains the least significant byte on little-endian machine and the most-significant byte on big-endian one. But my answer respects only little-endian. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.

The code below is related to a little-endian machine. I didn't check it against big-endian. According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0) BitConverter.GetBytes writes the least significant byte of a number into the first element of byteArray on little-endian machine. Then it writes the next more significant byte to the second element of byteArray, and so on.

The order of elements of byte array resulting from BitConverter.GetBytes depends on machine endianness.

So this is what happens in your little-endian machine.

3328 is D00 in hex view. 00 is the least significant byte, D is the most significant byte.
Let's see what happens when you transmit the whole number to BitConverter.GetBytes(x).

It converts your number to the array with the first member being 00 and the second one being D.
(v[0] = 0; v[1] = D)

Let's take a look at what happens in

ToBinaryString method with byte array

```
    string[] strArr = new string[v.Length]
```

which turns out to be
strArr = new sting [2]

then

```
    for(int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
```

truns out to be
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)

At the first pass, you get

```
    strArr[0] = ToBinaryString(v[0]);
```

=>
strArr[0] = "00000000"// since you deal with a pure zero value.

At the second pass, you get

```
    strArr[1] = ToBinaryString(v[1]);
```

=>

```
    Convert.ToString(D, 2)
```

=> 1101

```
    1101.PadLeft(8, '0')
```

=>

00001101

Now let's take a look at

```
    string.Join("", strArr)
```

That's it

```
v[0] + v[1] = "00000000" + "00001101"
```

i.e.
It returns 0000000000001101

Try

```
    public static string ToBinaryString(byte[] v)
    {
        string[] strArr = new string[v.Length];
        for(int i = v.Length, j = 0; i > 0; i--, j++)
        {
            strArr[i-1] = ToBinaryString(v[j]);
        }
        return string.Join("", strArr);
    }
```

res:  0000110100000000
res2: 0000110100000000

Regards.

Comment: string.Join("", strArr) forms a string from left to right, using array members from one with the least index to the biggest index. In positional numeral systems, including hex and decimal, we form numbers from left to right, with the leftmost integer place being the biggest. So one has to take it into account dealing with byte arrays. The leftmost byte in string value matches the element with the biggest index in a byte array.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanations. I especially appreciate the cross check against the hex version at the beginning.

Comment: In fact it I think it turned out that my code was correct and one would not need to go through the byte loop backwards. So if, then the other way was wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what lines of code you talk about. Be more specific, please.

Comment: I tested and debugged again with an example from wikipedia: int 16_909_060
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-Reihenfolge
This example has the bytes (their values) numbered from 1 to 4 and the debugger shows them stored as 4 3 2 1 meaning the correct binary string will be: 00000100 00000011 00000010 00000001. And this I create with for (int i=0, i<bArr.Length;i++) strArr[i] = ....

Comment: for some reason my wrong expectation always was that int 1 would look like (wrong) 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 instead of (correct) 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000

Comment: Yes, and the first representation looks correct for 32-bit big endian, though.